# Random request type specified in gon params in controller action

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to generalize my code and decide in the cotroller what request type i'll be using:

```
  function success() {
    var key = gon.pathAndFilename;
    var params = {};
    params.filePath = key;

    $.gon.requestType(gon.postRequestPath, // post, patch, get 
      params
    ).done(function() {
      location.reload();
    });
  }
```

in controller:

`gon.requestType = ?`

please help. thanks

Comment: Your question is... unclear. Could you share more information? What is `gon`? What are you trying to achieve? If you want to perform different actions on the same path with different request-types, you can achieve it by configuring `routes.rb`